# Small *nix based proxy server

Tags: linux, debian, proxy, proxy-server

I am currently running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and was looking for a small proxy server I could run on it. I know of squid but that is way more then what I need. I basically just want to be able to route my irc through my server instead of through my home ip.

<sub>And no this is not for serverfault since this question is for me/myself/I and not for a customers server</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its just irc, you could use a [irc bouncer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BNC_%28software%29) or simple ssh tunneling. Alternatively do it the 1337 way and run the irc client on the server, with say, irssi+screen!

Comment: bouncer would be a no go, and I don't want to cli my irc. But the ssh tunneling seems to be the easiest way.

Comment: SSH tunneling also has the advantage of hiding the fact that its irc ;).